# Can there be an administrative organization inside the US, above the state level?

Tags: united-states, constitution, us-state-laws, state-legislatures

According to the [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60864/what-can-be-the-form-of-the-union-of-states-that-will-abide-by-the-constitutio) about chairman West's phrase:

> Perhaps law-abiding states should bond together and form a Union of states that will abide by the constitution

**Is it constitutionally possible to have some above-state organization/structure inside the US?**

Comment: I think the quote is referring to the United States of America, which is a union of states with a shared constitution. I don't think it's implying a new union be formed, it's hinting at such a formation knowing that there already is such a union.

Comment: "that will abide by the constitution" is the silly part though, because all states have to. So on its face that is a vacuous proposal. (I din't DV by the way. Your q is reasonable, even though the quote is almost certainly not the best motivating example.) What that quote really relates to are the bouts of #Texit one sees after Republicans lose a presidential election. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_secession_movements#Opinion_polling

Comment: I feel like you're misunderstanding this. Your question is asking about interstate compacts, but your quote is about succession. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no. [Interstate compacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_compact) do require federal approval, but in many cases approval is assumed unless explicitly stated otherwise. Most commonly these are to manage shared resources like lakes, rivers, oil, or forests. Other examples are related to education standards, tax regulations, or the several regional Covid pacts.

Generally these pacts have no real power as that would require explicit approval by congress. They mostly create rules and regulations that member states are encouraged to adopt.

Answer (score 5):

An example of an administrative organization that involves more than one state is the [Port Authority of New York and New Jersey](https://www.panynj.gov/port-authority/en/about.html). Of course, it has authority over a fairly narrow range of places and activities. It was authorized by Congress in 1921.